Calculate threshold, so that 99% of random string have higher entropy
I am trying to calculate the distribution of the Shannon entropy for all possible random strings of length N.
(by random, I mean that each letter at each position is picked with equal probability)
To calculate the Shannon entropy, I am using a formula similar to e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979208/145999.
prob = [ float(string.count(c)) / len(string) for c in dict.fromkeys(list(string)) ]
entropy = - sum([ p * math.log(p) / math.log(2.0) for p in prob ])

Now I am trying to find a threshold t, so that e.g. 99% of all random strings will have a higher entropy than t.
How can I calculate this threshold entropy, given the length of the string, the number of possible different letters, and the desired fraction of strings that should have higher entropy?

The exact calculation is too hard for me.  Are you sure this is what you want?  As the length increases, the standard deviation of entropies gets very small.  99%-ile and 1%-ile will be quite close.  What do you want to use it for?  Maybe an approximation will do.

This is for finding a reasonable entropy threshold to determine if a string could be a randomly generated password. The strings can be quite short, 10-100 chars. I can easily get a rough approximation by brute-force generating a million strings, but would still be interested in a formula for the exact value, so that I can run it on the fly for an arbitrarily constrained string.

The exact formula requires summing over the set of possible frequency distributions Each of which has a different entropy. Which grows as a polynomial of degree the number of characters. Admittedly with good constants. But still, the brute force approximation is likely to be faster to calculate in practice.

0123456789 has the maximum possible Shannon entropy for a 10 character password.  So does monkey2953 and yanotsecur.  I think you should use a more sophisticated model.

I am quite aware. But the point is that if a string has less entropy than say 99.999% of random passwords, I can be fairly certain that it is not a password, so any more sophisticated methods such as asking the user, can be skipped. It is a way to reduce false positives. And the majority of non-random strings can be excluded that way, without even having to try to calculate their kolmogorov complexity, which is a little too sophisticated.

It seems like the quick-and-dirty method would be to do a monte-carlo:
from typing import *
import math
import random

def get_entropy(string: str) -> int:
    prob = [float(string.count(c)) / len(string) for c in dict.fromkeys(list(string))]
    return - sum([p * math.log2(p) for p in prob])

def get_random_string(length=10, chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):
    return random.choices(chars, k=length)

def monte_carlo_entropy(random_function: Callable[[], str], num_sims=10000) -> list[int]:
    entropies = []
    for i in range(num_sims):
        entropies.append(get_entropy(random_function()))
    entropies.sort()
    return entropies

def get_percentile(sorted_entropies: list[int], percentile=0.99) -> int:
    index = int(len(sorted_entropies) * percentile)
    return sorted_entropies[index]

entropies = monte_carlo_entropy(lambda: get_random_string(10))
print(get_percentile(entropies, 0.99))

For that specific length, character set, and uniforn distribution, I get 3.321 bits.
It's worth noting that this entropy definition is more than a little bit weird and probably not suited for this application. No matter how long the password is, a lowercase a-z password will have a maximum of entropy of -26 * (1/26 * log2(1/26)) ~= 4.700.

I agree with the others that shannon entropy is probably not what you want for your particular application, however I wanted to still offer a solution (a) for your own hands-on experimentation and (b) for anyone else who happens to stumble upon this question that does need the calculation for other purposes.
Note that we can rewrite the equation for shannon entropy to deal only in (large) integers, to avoid floating point issues until the very end.

We will use the right-hand-side summation at the end for evaluation to actual entropy values, but in our dynamic programming table we'll use the product variant.
The basic premise is that we can iterate over all the lengths of strings up to full_length and character sets sizes of up to full_alpha_size and incrementally build up a table of (adjusted) entropy values and their respective counts (using a tiny bit of combinatorics). Once this table is built up, we'll iterate over the entropy values for full_length and full_alpha_size, converting them to their corresponding shannon entropy values (becoming constant floats), and yield them along with their corresponding counts.
We can then use this function, generate all possible entropy values and the corresponding count of distinct strings which have that entropy, build up a cumulative count in increasing entropy, and find the first entropy that exceeds our target percentile.
Code:
from collections import defaultdict
from math import ceil, comb, log2

def count_entropy_values(full_length, full_alpha_size):
    table = [[defaultdict(int) for _ in range(full_alpha_size + 1)]
                               for _ in range(full_length + 1)]
    
    for alpha_size in range(full_alpha_size + 1):
        table[0][alpha_size][1] = 1
        
    for length in range(1, full_length + 1):
        for alpha_size in range(1, full_alpha_size + 1):
            for repeat_count in range(length + 1):
                for entropy, table_count in table[length-repeat_count][alpha_size-1].items():
                    new_entropy = entropy * repeat_count ** repeat_count
                    table[length][alpha_size][new_entropy] += table_count * comb(length, repeat_count)
                    

    for entropy, table_count in table[full_length][full_alpha_size].items():
        real_entropy = log2(full_length) - log2(entropy) / full_length
        yield real_entropy, table_count

def calculate_entropy_threshold(length, alpha_size, percentile):
    table = sorted(count_entropy_values(length, alpha_size))
    
    target = ceil(alpha_size ** length * percentile)
    total_count = 0
    
    for entropy, count in table:
        total_count += count
        if total_count >= target:
            return entropy

For the same target (strings of length of 10 with 26 characters to choose from), and seeking the 99-th percentile entropy:
>>> calculate_entropy_threshold(10, 26, 0.99)
3.321928094887362

Note that this is the same value obtained empirically in Kaia's answer.
This takes about a millisecond on my machine. Larger values will inevitably be slower, however for length:30 alphabet:100 it still only took a few seconds, so hopefully that's still fast enough for most practical usage.
If you want to query for multiple different lengths and character set sizes, you can edit the code to reuse the dynamic programming table to avoid recomputing that every time (which is the most expensive part).
